# click handler is not working on image

Tags: html, event-handling

Hello every one I have wrote a simple code in html5 in which I am calling the click handler of image and display the alert but I don't know why it isn't working can any one please guide Where am I doing wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script> 
function clickhandler(){
alert ("I am called");
}
</script>
<style>
 #div1
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;

}
</style>
<body>
<div id="div1">
<img src="myimage.png" onClick="clickhandler" draggable="false" />
<img>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

THANKS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
<img src="myimage.png" onClick="clickhandler()" draggable="false" />
```

The onClick attribute should be a function call or statement.

Comment: @Jacob <header >
 <span><img src="img/img_zones/header-arrow.png" alt="" onclick="hello()"></span>
 <h1 id="header"></h1>
 </header> and the function is function hello(){
  console.log("jdaghsjagwdjka");
  alert("skjfhiskhfk");
 }

Answer (score 0):

You should also move your style and script tags inside the head tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script> 
function clickhandler(){
alert("I am called");
}
</script>
<style>
 #div1
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;

}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Exponential_Function_(Abs_Imag_Part_at_Infinity)_Density.png" onclick="clickhandler()" draggable="false" />

</div>
</body>
</html>
```